# Pass children tags as props to components in Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am busy creating a modal using ReactJS and manged to get the basic modal up and running. I have two attributes (show and handleClose) that I assign to the Modal component and I am using Functions with Hooks. I have two p-tags (children) in my parent file App.js as below,

```
<Modal show={mod} handleClose={hideModal} >
              <p>Modal</p>
              <p>Data</p>
            </Modal>
```

I want to pass the p-tags as props to my Modal component as I do with show and handleClose attributes. My question, how do you pass children tags to components with Functions and Hooks?

Below is my full working code, file App.js,

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Modal from './Modal';

function App() {
  const[mod, setMod] = useState(false);
  
  const showModal = () =>{
      setMod(true)
  }

  const hideModal = () =>{
    setMod(false)
  }
  
  return (
      <div>
        <h1 >My React modal</h1>
        <Modal show={mod} handleClose={hideModal} >
          <p>Modal</p>
          <p>Data</p>
        </Modal>
        <button type="button" onClick={showModal}>Show modal</button>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Modal.js,

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Modal (props) {
    
        return (
            <ShowModal show={props.show} handleClose={props.handleClose}/>
        );    
}

function ShowModal (props){ 
   const showHideClassName = props.show ? 'modal display-block' : 'modal display-none';
    
   return (
        <div className={showHideClassName} onClick={props.handleClose}>
            <section className="modal-main">
                {props.children}
                <button onClick={props.handleClose}>Close</button>
            </section>
        </div>
   );
}

export default Modal;
```

App.css,

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

  .modal-main {
    position:fixed;
    background: white;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    top:10%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }

.display-block {
  display: block;
}

.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing Props in case of Hooks and Functions works similar to that of Class Component.

You are not able to view the children props of Modal is because you are trying to access them inside the ShowModal and ShowModal component does not have any children of its own. So you need to pass the children props that you received from App.js's Modal Component to ShowModal's.

Solution:

Change your ShowModal component to below.

```
<ShowModal show={props.show} handleClose={props.handleClose}>
  {props.children}
</ShowModal>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Advice**: You have to do a bit of prop drilling. Don't spilt code for some small usecases, it makes the prop passing job hard.

Just wrap the `props.children` of Modal inside the `ShowModal` component & as you are calling `props.children` from `ShowModal`, this will get passed to it too.

**Code**:

```js
//Modal
function Modal (props) {
    
        return (
            <ShowModal show={props.show} handleClose={props.handleClose}>
              {props.children}
            </ShowModal>
        );    
}
//============================================
//or for short
 function Modal (props) {
    
        return (
            <ShowModal {...props}/> {/*As you don't have other props to use in Modal just pass with spread operator & that will pass all the props available to ShowModal*/}
        );    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest the ShowModal works fine alone as a Modal.
2. By adding paragraphOne and paragraphTwo as conditional props you have your solution without demanding them for future cases.

Suggestion in code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Modal (props){ 
   const showHideClassName = props.show ? 'modal display-block' : 'modal display-none';
    
   return (
        <div className={showHideClassName} onClick={props.handleClose}>
            <section className="modal-main">
                {props.paragraphOne && (
                  <p>{props.paragraphOne}</p>
                )}

                {props.paragraphTwo && (
                  <p>{props.paragraphTwo}</p>
                )}

                {props.children}
                <button onClick={props.handleClose}>Close</button>
            </section>
        </div>
   );
}

export default Modal;
```